# Which way to create a canvas pattern from a dataToURL-image string as directly as possible?

Tags: javascript, performance, canvas, html5-canvas, race-condition

I'm using an image that I much previously had made by

```
var patternImageAsDataURL= canvasObject.toDataURL('image/png');
```

In a later stage I want to make a canvas pattern object. The following code doesn't work - I assume the image is simply not loaded when going to the last line, where it is needed in the createPattern function.

```
var img = document.createElement('img');
img.src = patternImageAsDataURL;
// canvasctx was created somewhere else in the program
pattern = canvasctx.createPattern(img,'repeat');
```

I get the error: `NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE:` on the last line. (And when using console.log on width and heigth of `img` between the two last lines, I see when it's not working the dimensions are `0`.)

When later on the same operation is done with the same dataURL, it does work. Though the image (img) should always be created anew. (Only reason I can see it's because of some internal optimization in Firefox. But that's offtopic here, unless someone does know the answer.) The width and height when printing them out to the console are correct then.

While I will quite soon program some pattern handling service, that should solve this, my question is in general and for speed concerns and for simplicity. (If I use some code with like 20 to 50 objects with patterns, I would prefer a lean solution over a memory or time saving function.)

> Could I somehow use the dataURL more directly (and faster) for the
>   createPattern function?
>   And:
>   Could I force the program to wait after the `img.src = patternImageAsDataURL;` command until the image is loaded, and then to go on processing the code? (Like in the synchronous mode of the XMLrequests.)

(Using the onload event of the image isn't feasible in the current program flow.)

This is running on Firefox 32, Win 7.

Answer (score 2):

**A faster, more direct way to create a pattern**

You can use a second canvas element as the source for a pattern.

This allows you to completely skip the interim step of creating an ImageURL and Image from your source canvas so your pattern creation will be faster.

[image]

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;

// Make a temporary canvas to be the template for a pattern
var pc=document.createElement('canvas');
var px=pc.getContext('2d');
pc.width=4;
pc.height=4;
px.fillStyle='palegreen';
px.fillRect(0,0,2,2);
px.fillRect(2,2,2,2);

// Use the temporary canvas as the image source for "createPattern"
var pattern=ctx.createPattern(pc,'repeat');
ctx.fillStyle=pattern;
ctx.fillRect(50,50,100,75);
ctx.strokeRect(50,50,100,75);
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<h4>Using a temporary canvas as source for a Pattern.</h4>
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```

Comment: I see...as you suspect, the "unavailable" error is caused by trying to use the image before it is fully loaded. You can fix that error by using the `Image.onload` callback. A workaround to your situation (that is neither faster nor more direct) is to create images/patterns from your imageURLs at the start of your app.  While the processing time would be the same, the user experience would be snappier because all the image manipulation would be preprocessed.

Answer (score 1):

## Option 1 - Canvas as image source

The obvious is of course to use the canvas itself as image source for the pattern.

`createPattern()` can take image, canvas, context (although not all browsers allow this) or even video as [source](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#2dcontext).

> CanvasPattern createPattern(CanvasImageSource image,
>        [TreatNullAs=EmptyString] DOMString repetition);

where `CanvasImageSource` is defined as:

> typedef (HTMLImageElement or
>                 HTMLVideoElement or
>                 HTMLCanvasElement or
>                 CanvasRenderingContext2D or
>                 ImageBitmap) CanvasImageSource;

This is also the only way that will allow you to not use `onload` at some point later (provided the pattern is generated and not drawn in from an image/video source).

*You cannot deal with asynchronous behavior without using callbacks (or promises), and expect the program to work properly. Period.*

## Option 2 - Data-URIs

If you for some reason cannot use the original canvas as source, you have to deal with the image asynchronously. Add a `onload` handler for it and continue from inside it:

```
var img = document.createElement('img');
img.onload = function() {
    pattern = canvasctx.createPattern(this, 'repeat');
    // continue from here..
};
img.src = patternImageAsDataURL;
```

Note that the process of this is relative slow due to the additional encoding/decoding process on top of the image handling itself. You can find more details about this in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23413320/canvas-todataurlimage-png-how-does-it-work-and-how-to-optimize-it/23413457#23413457).

## Option 3 - Blob and object-URL

A [Blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FBlob) lets you store the data in binary form. This is preferred over storing the binary data as encoded string as with data-URIs. This will be faster to embed as well as extract compared to data-URIs.

You can use URL form with the Blob and use that as image source.

*First create the Blob directly from canvas:*

```
var patternImageAsBlob = canvas.toBlob(...);  //IE: msToBlob()
```

This is also an asynchronous call so you need to take that into account.

**For example:**

```
var patternAsBlob;

canvas.toBlob(function(blob) {
    patternAsBlob = blob;
    // continue from here
}
```

Then when you need it as an image, generate an Object-URL for it like this:

```
  var img = new Image(),
      url = URL.createObjectURL(patternAsBlob);

    img.onload = function() {
        URL.revokeObjectURL(url);  // clean up by removing the url object
        pattern = canvasctx.createPattern(this, 'repeat');
        // continue from here..
    };
    img.src = url;
```

### Tips

If you have several images to load and set, it would be better to make an image loader to load in all resources to an array, when done create the patterns.

This will simplify the asynchronous chain-calling (optionally use promises, but this is not yet supported in IE without a polyfill).

You may need a polyfill for toBlob in older browser. One can be found **[here](https://github.com/blueimp/JavaScript-Canvas-to-Blob)**.

You may need to "unprefix" the `createObjectURL()`, here is one way:

```
 var domURL = self.URL || self.webkitURL || self;
 var url = domURL.createObjectURL( ... );
```

Comment: @John 1) all image loading is async in JS as well as the toBlob(). You could use a png-decoder and load the data synchronous by ajax, but this is not recommended and increase load time for your page, decoding time etc. Just bad UX (time, blocking etc.). 2) A data-uri is always 33% larger compared to byte data due to how it is encoded (base-64). A single string-char uses 2 bytes due to utf-16, so a blob will always win. You can store the color data but this would be the same as storing uncompressed image data. If you use string then the storage space is double compared to just a bitmap..

Comment: @John no problem. The browser will be a tad faster as it uses compiled code, but pngtoy is pretty fast too :)